# Sorting a vector in descending order within two ranges

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, stdvector

Say I have a vector of integers:

```
std::vector<int> indices;
for (int i=0; i<15; i++) indices.push_back(i);
```

Then I sort it in descending order:

```
sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [](int first, int second) -> bool{return indices[first] > indices[second];})
for (int i=0; i<15; i++) printf("%i\n", indices[i]);
```

This produces the following:

```
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Now I want to have the numbers 3, 4, 5, and 6 to be moved to the end, and keep the descending order for them (preferably without having to use `sort` for the second time). I.e., here is what I want:

```
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
2
1
0
6
5
4
3
```

How should I modify the comparison function of the `std::sort` to achieve that?

Comment: `return indices[first] > indices[second]` Don't you mean `return first < second;`?

Comment: Make sure your comparator compares them as "greater" than all other values, and if its comparing two values that are either both of these or neither of these values, normal comparison order applies. Very simple.

Comment: For a simple descending sort, `std::greater` from `<functional>` can be used in place of your lambda. As to your question, writing a more verbose comparator that ensures your values compare the way you want might be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @acraig5075, in descending order it should be `return first > second`.

Comment: @acraig5075 I feel like I'm missing something, or do people not know the difference between **ascending** and **descending**?

Comment: @acraig5075 , @ks1322 , yes, `return first > second` of course

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)?

Comment: @sweenish I actually do know the difference between the two :), but I had a typo, and I'm too late to edit it. My point was to emphasize the error of the indexing.

Comment: @super forget my stupid comment, I deleted it.

Comment: instead of `for (int i=0; i<15; i++) indices.push_back(i);` use `std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);` (after initializing the vector with size 15 of course `std::vector<int> indices(15);`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your comparison function is wrong since the values you get as `first` and `second` are the elements of the `std::vector`. Therefore, there is no need to use them as indices. So, you need to change

```
return indices[first] > indices[second];
```

to

```
return first > second;
```

**Now, regarding the problem you try to solve...**

You can leave 3, 4, 5 and 6 out of comparison with other elements and still compare it with each other:

```cpp
std::sort(
    indices.begin(), indices.end(),
    [](int first, int second) -> bool {
        bool first_special = first >= 3 && first <= 6;
        bool second_special = second >= 3 && second <= 6;
        if (first_special != second_special)
            return second_special;
        else
            return first > second;
    }
);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMTMBWUgAdUCwuto9QxMzb19/Ohs7RyMXN0lPJRU1OgYCZmICIONTcyTMVQC0jIIoh2dXD0V0zOyQvJrS23LYyoSASkVUA2JkDgByKQBmW2RDLABqcSGddQUCYkxmI2nscQAGAEFh0fHMKZmANwKiYlWN7ckR2jGDSemdNmASQgQVobWti9sCCaNmWwQdpTADssi2E0hE3m6BAIGOqhIDx%2BqwmtnwfQU03BmyhExoxAmEB%2BaOmABF1tjSTNOO4qXg5HJgei8JiAHReAwKBAAfSczGQAGtie1sRc8TC4QoSAQIOK8VCWeyXMBAZ00dpWZgFGzLEDSPKFVN3LJ3GTifR8XhiPNSBrfko0NpgQBaVFOVD6UE4o1Gj1eqjW%2BY8hReAp4NgHMlWm2/cnkiYANlBOnEIJ0MfmUYT7hTaYzgdj2aG0e4efTmbjJYTQzFEN9eP9rGhBTo6BDYeQEebCcdbeL0eT%2BfzLad6AHE1zw4rfe0E7L04zs/H8ZLE1rQx9DcVVCJheDofDkakiZPo7bHaPrFF9e3CsWBB6tErB2w5%2B0ddxd4myiUaN31BBgQl5dmwN5ft%2BUIPk%2B%2BJsEon6Qb%2B%2Bx4ABy4gd24GQXi0HEM%2BCwGJgCHfkhhpYThz77lWb7LkRRppmSpGipupEEkSJIMiWlKbtSOi0vSjIyMCXjED8VBypIkhSO4DLuDotBSOYGoYtq4gmjJZJMVukLkRMXE4vR/SdKwID9O4/SkKY/TrOZqAmamMhyNC3S9PswycOZBAmdZ7SdIKIDuJIbKJkMILrCC7ggpwAAc6y0om8VCCZ3DmZZ1mkLZ/TmQoIDrKQnlWYZpBwLAMCICgqBGF4eDsGQFAQGglXVZUwAAJzmIGrAEK42UQE4XnmU4tgZAAniZ7mkA1RhaAQADytCsKNBWkFg/yiOw/XLdaJx4Mc2VLZgAAeBQGF1G0/MoG2sHgTjECNehYGNHkiUYj2dDQ9BMGwHA8PwgjCKIKACfIV1ONlkCdKgXgpLQe0ui6MLkhIDkyJw435IUGgQJYdSmJwFjaGUMRxIIPh%2BNDOMk%2BE0OExUbh4%2Bj0PFLU%2Bg5IIDNFI0NOtHT1QlBT9Oc80ROVJwnTSj0fRcEZJlmRZG0ZQdUWJi6iZlsAyDIBMLVspIRK4IQJBTFceMTHojU1UbQyi6bQMef1PmkH5IVsp4xn9MlpAve4uWpTZJlZTleX20VpUQEg3QEJyBDkJQDVVTVgiYPgpyCO9jAsOtnDmAA7rdXivYlpkpfLJluRM2evBMivK6rEzq5r2uSHbBUOwgSxYG4%2Bpux7Xs%2ByXmWKIH%2BXeb5IDcCCbJDImkhtdwkhRZwLVRdwQxDLwbtDMXS0Zc3I%2BF03cvb/7Qct50xw2gEY9AA%3D)

Comment: @NutCracker Yes, I agree it's nicer to have the top criterion first.

Answer (score 5):

Functions from the [standard algorithms library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) like `iota`, `sort`, `find`, `rotate` and `copy` would make your life easier. Your example comes down to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


int main()
{
  std::vector<int> indices(15);
  std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);
  std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), std::greater<>());

  auto a = std::find(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 6);
  auto b = std::find(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 3);
  std::rotate(a, b + 1, indices.end());

  std::copy(indices.begin(), indices.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
2
1
0
6
5
4
3
```

---

@TedLyngmo in the comments makes the good point that it could/should be improved with:

```
auto a = std::lower_bound(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 6, std::greater<int>{});
auto b = a + 4;
```

Comment: `auto b = a + 4;` is wrong (if you want to keep consistency with the previous snippet). It should be `auto b = a + 3;` because in the `std::rotate` you use `b + 1`

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1

Straightforward approach with a *non-linear* comparator.

```
inline constexpr bool SpecialNumber(const int n) noexcept {
  return n < 7 && 2 < n;
}

void StrangeSortSol1(std::vector<int>* v) {
  std::sort(v->begin(), v->end(), [](const int a, const int b) noexcept {
    const bool aSpecial = SpecialNumber(a);
    const bool bSpecial = SpecialNumber(b);

    if (aSpecial && bSpecial) return b < a;
    if (aSpecial) return false;
    if (bSpecial) return true;
    return b < a;
  });
}
```

### Solution 2

Using `std::algorithm`s (partition)!

```
inline constexpr bool SpecialNumber(const int n) noexcept {
  return n < 7 && 2 < n;
}

void StrangeSortSol2(std::vector<int>* v) {
  auto pivot = std::partition(v->begin(), v->end(), std::not_fn(SpecialNumber));
  std::sort(v->begin(), pivot, std::greater{});
  std::sort(pivot, v->end(), std::greater{});
}
```

---

#### Performance Considerations

It may look like the second solution is slower because of the overhead of partition. Probably it's not, because of cache and miss-branch prediction in modern processors.

[Benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/YbKTgt_NDZuWib3rV5ANMN3-RWc)

Comment: Any good compiler should transform `n <= 6 && 3 <= n`  to whatever works best for the target CPU so you gain nothing by introducing the numbers 2 and 7 but potential confusion - and why take a pointer to the vector instead of a reference?

Comment: Don't use ` const int number` as argument function

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Why?

Comment: @HeapOverflow Because it is the same without using const :).

Comment: @AntoineMorrier I don't think it's the same. Doesn't the `const` tell the reader that the function doesn't change the value? In this particular case of a one-liner it might be clear, but in general it isn't.

Comment: @HeapOverflow the argument is passed by value (i.e nor reference nor pointers). So the reader will know that the data will be copied, so the value given to the function will never be changed ;)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier I'm not talking about the caller's value. I'm talking about the value inside the function. If I'm about to read the function code and I see the `const`, I know that it'll be the same value throughout the function, don't I?

Comment: @HeapOverflow You will, but it is probably useless and can be bad for performance. (Move semantic dont apply on const object :-) ).

Comment: @AntoineMorrier It has absolutely no impact on performance in this case, and guards against accidental changes (e. g. `++n` when `++m` was intended for some other temporary variable). In certain other languages, like Rust, const arguments are the default.

Comment: i know in this case it has no performance impact, but I am not sure it has a good impact else where to put const where it don't have to be.
I agree const arguments must be the default everywhere also :).